# "_TWTRScribeEventImpressionElement" and TwitterKit Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode7, twitter-fabric

I'm using Xcode 7. 
After updating Fabric framework and TwitterCore I can't build my project. I Have problem with `_TWTRScribeEventImpressionElement` and other files in TwitterKit.
I'm tryied to update TwitterKit but it did not help.

Error is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:

  "_TWTRScribeEventImpressionElement", referenced from:

      -[TWTRScribeSink didShareTweetWithID:shareType:] in TwitterKit(TWTRScribeSink.o)
      +[TWTRScribeSink tweetLoadNamespace] in TwitterKit(TWTRScribeSink.o)
      +[TWTRScribeSink tweetViewImpressionNamespaceWithStyle:] in TwitterKit(TWTRScribeSink.o)
      +[TWTRScribeSink tweetViewShareNamespace] in TwitterKit(TWTRScribeSink.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Has somebody seen such problem?

Comment: Are you still having this problem? Does the CocoaPods install method help to get all of the most up-to-date versions?

Comment: Were you able to ever solve this?